# Format Gulp Output for Clearer Errors

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Is there a way to format the output that Gulp sends to the console?
I have a gulp watch task for my javascript:

```
gulp.task('js', ['lintjs', 'testjs'], function(){
    //something
});
```

But if my linting task fails and then my test task succeeds, there is a tiny red error about the linting failing followed by a load of green about karma starting up and passing the tests. This often leads to me missing the fact that the linting failed.
Is there a way to format the output so that I can see if any tasks failed? Or possibly report on any failed tasks at the bottom of the console window?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852814/gulp-jshint-how-to-fail-the-build
By failing the build on linting errors you will not be able to miss them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp-util`.

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gutil.log('stuff happened', 'Really it did', gutil.colors.magenta('123'));
gutil.beep();
```

For more details you can read doc on [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util).