# How to fail Grunt build if JSHint fails during watch task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jshint

This seems like a basic question but I can't figure out how to do it. [This is how to do it in gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852814/gulp-jshint-how-to-fail-the-build).

I want when I save a file with a jshint error to fail the Grunt build. The output states that jshint failed but Grunt still completes successfully.

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: ['/scripts/{,**}/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all']
      }
    }
})
```

I know there is [`grunt.fail`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.fail) but how would I use it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gist will report a `jshint` error via the CLI and fail to execute any subsequent build steps when saving the `.js` file.

You will need to adapt according to your requirements :

#### Directory structure:

```
project
│
├──package.json
│
├───scripts
│   │
│   └───test.js
│
├─── Gruntfile.js
│
└───node_modules
    │
    └─── ...
```

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "stack40031078",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Answer to stack question 40031078",
  "author": "RobC",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

#### Gruntfile.js

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // VALIDATE JS
        jshint: {
            // Note we're using 'src:' instead of 'all:' below.
            files: {
                src: './scripts/{,**}/*.js'
            },
            options: {
                // Use your jshint config here or define them in
                // a separate .jshintrc file and set the flag to:
                //
                // jshintrc: true
                curly: true,
                eqeqeq: true,
                immed: true,
                latedef: true,
                newcap: true,
                noarg: true,
                sub: true,
                undef: true,
                boss: true,
                eqnull: true,
                browser: true,
                smarttabs: true,
                globals: {}
            }
        },

        // WATCH THE JS FILES
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['./scripts/{,**}/*.js'],
                // NOTE: we're not using 'newer:jshint:all' below, just 'newer:jshint'
                tasks: ['newer:jshint' /* <-- Add subsequent build tasks here. E.g. ,'concat' - A registered task can also be added. E.g. 'default' */]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [

    ]);

};
```

#### test.js

```js
console.log('Hello World');

var test = function() {
    return 'test';
};
```

### Testing the demo gist

1. `cd` to the `project` directory
2. run `$ npm install`
3. run `$ grunt watch`
4. Open and make a simple edit to `test.js`, (e.g. add a new line to the end of the file), and save the change.

The CLI reports the error as follows:

```
    Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
       ./scripts/test.js
          1 |console.log('Hello Universe');
             ^ 'console' is not defined.

    >> 1 error in 1 file
    Warning: Task "jshint:files" failed. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
    Completed in 0.965s at Fri Oct 14 2016 10:22:59 GMT+0100 (BST) - Waiting...
```

**NOTE:**

Any subsequent build tasks specified in the `tasks` array of the `watch.js` object, (e.g. `concat` as per commented in the `Gruntfile.js`), will not be invoked using this gist as the `jshint` task fails (... and the `concat` task has not been defined of course!).

However, when the JavaScript file/s successfully pass the `jshint` task, any subsequent build tasks that are defined in the `tasks` array of the `watch.js` object will be invoked.

I hope this helps!