# Using requirejs optimizer node module with Gulp

Tags: requirejs, gulp, amd, r.js

There's [gulp-requirejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-requirejs) plugin, but it's [blacklisted](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json#L9) with the following message: "use the [require.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs) module directly".

The docs are quite sparse, how would I best use it in conjunction with Gulp build task?

In the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#optimizer) there's an example:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

var config = {
    baseUrl: '../appDir/scripts',
    name: 'main',
    out: '../build/main-built.js'
};

requirejs.optimize(config, function (buildResponse) {
    //buildResponse is just a text output of the modules
    //included. Load the built file for the contents.
    //Use config.out to get the optimized file contents.
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(config.out, 'utf8');
}, function(err) {
    //optimization err callback
});
```

But that doesn't help me much... Here's my best try:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    r = require('requirejs').optimize;

var config2 = {
    baseUrl: 'src/js',
    name: 'config',
    out: 'dist/js/main-built.js'
};

gulp.task('scripts3', function() {
    gulp.src(['src/js/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(r(config)
   .pipe(gulp.dest(config.out))
});
```

But the requirejs module doesn't use streams, so it won't work.

There's also the very Gulp friendly [amd-optimize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-optimize) but it's not the same as r.js, yet.

Comment: Well I have not used gulp. But I have good expertise around RequireJS and grunt and non grunt... So what is this streams, cant we use like normal task in gulp?

Comment: Gulp uses [Node streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), and [vinyl](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl). Vinyl is black magic for me at this point, [here's](https://medium.com/@contrahacks/gulp-3828e8126466) a great post on it. I also just found [this issue](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/785) dealing with just this.

Comment: I could just run the shell command with gulp-shell.

Comment: Using amd-optimize is fine. Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978361/using-gulp-to-build-requirejs-project-gulp-requirejs#26079448

Comment: @OweRReLoaDeD amd-optimize is pretty great! But it has it's limitations compared to r.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ended up running the `r.js` build command with gulp-shell:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell');

// Run the r.js command, so simple taks :)
gulp.task('scripts', shell.task([
    'r.js -o build/r/build.js'
]))
```

It takes roughly 2 seconds to run, not too long at all.

The r settings are defined in an external `build.js` file that Gulp knows nothing about.

Comment: Sorry but for this you dont need Gupl. You can run it via: npm run "task"

Answer (score 8):

To do this without invoking the shell, you can do it like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rjs = require('requirejs'),

    config = {
        baseUrl: '../appDir/scripts',
        name: 'main',
        out: '../build/main-built.js'
    };

gulp.task('scripts', function(cb){
    rjs.optimize(config, function(buildResponse){
        // console.log('build response', buildResponse);
        cb();
    }, cb);
});
```

see: https://github.com/phated/requirejs-example-gulpfile/blob/master/gulpfile.js