# r.js optimizer not taking from config

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, gulp, r.js

I am using gulp and [requirejs-optimize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-requirejs-optimize)

My ***init.js***

```
;
(function(require) {

    "use strict";

    //Constants

    require.config({

        paths: {
            "angular": "app/libs/angular/angular.min",
            "domready": "app/libs/domReady/domReady",
            "angular-ui-router": "app/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min",
            "angular-bootstrap": "app/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min",
            "App": "app/app",
            "angular-animate": "app/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min",
            "ui-bootstrap-tpls": "app/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min",
            "enums": "app/enums"
        },
        waitSecond: 0,
        shim: {
            "angular": {
                exports: "angular",
                deps: []
            },

            "angular-ui-router": {
                deps: ["angular"]
            },

            "angular-bootstrap": {
                deps: ["angular"]
            },

            "ui-bootstrap-tpls": {
                deps: ["angular-bootstrap"]
            },

            "domready": {
                deps: []
            },

            "App": {
                deps: ["angular"]
            },

            "angular-animate": {
                deps: ["angular"],
                exports: "angular"
            }
        }
    });

    //This module defines all the Global constants for the app
    define("CONST", [], {
        templatesPath: "views/",
        URL: "https://saltjs-nirus.c9.io/service"
    });

    define(["require", "domready"], function(require, domready) {
        domready(function() {
            require(["angular", "App", "app/router"], function(angular, app) {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ["salt"]);
            });
        });
    });

})(window.requirejs);
```

and my **Build config file** is as below

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var requirejsOptimize = require('gulp-requirejs-optimize');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(["./../ClientApp/init.js", "./../ClientApp/app/libs/domReady/domReady.js"])
        .pipe(requirejsOptimize(function(file) {
            return {
                baseUrl: "./../ClientApp/",
                useStrict: true,
                optimize: "uglify",                 
                paths: {
                    "angular": "app/libs/angular/angular.min",
                    "domready": "app/libs/domReady/domReady",
                    "angular-ui-router": "app/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min",
                    "angular-bootstrap": "app/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min",
                    "App": "app/app",
                    "angular-animate": "app/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min",
                    "ui-bootstrap-tpls": "app/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min",
                    "enums": "app/enums"
                },
                shim: {
                    "angular": {
                        exports: "angular",
                        deps: []
                    },

                    "angular-ui-router": {
                        deps: ["angular"]
                    },

                    "angular-bootstrap": {
                        deps: ["angular"]
                    },

                    "ui-bootstrap-tpls": {
                        deps: ["angular-bootstrap"]
                    },

                    "domready": {
                        deps: []
                    },

                    "App": {
                        deps: ["angular"]
                    },

                    "angular-animate": {
                        deps: ["angular"],
                        exports: "angular"
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./../build/final.js'));
});

gulp.task("default", ['scripts'])
```

**Problem:** When run `gulp` i am getting below error

> ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/workspace/ClientApp/domReady.js'

Here the requirejs optimizer is not taking the `path` option specified in the build-config file, instead its searching for the physical path which is throwing the error. How can i force the optimizer to lookup to the `path` option specified in the r.js build config and pick up the files from there for optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally i figured out to make it work:**

I switched from gulp-optimizer to straight Node r.js as Gulp dev have suggested to use the optimizer directly as r.js is not compatible with gulp.

[Git Blacklist.json:](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json)

> "gulp-module-requirejs": "use the require.js module directly",

Below is my config file:

```
({
    mainConfigFile: "./../ClientApp/app/init.js",
    name: "init",
    baseUrl: "./../ClientApp/app/",
    insertRequire:["init"],
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    out: "./../ClientApp/build/final.js",
    wrap: true,
    optimize: "uglify",
    uglify: {
        toplevel: true,
        ascii_only: true,
        beautify: false,
        max_line_length: 1000,
        defines: {
            DEBUG: ['name', 'false']
        },
        no_mangle: true
    }
});
```

I am using uglify for minification provided by require.js

**Explanation:**

- **mainConfigFile:** Use this option to point out to the file where you have defined your `paths`, `shims`, `deps` etc. RequireJs is intelligent enough to pick the config from this declaration for processing(they use regex pattern to filter this part, so be careful. Refer their [DOC](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js))
- **name** : An entrypoint module name. Define this where your executin kicks-off. PS: If you have config and EP is the same file, require will detect this and add the `name` to your defined call.
- **insertRequire:** This will insert a require statement at the end which will trigger the execution of your code. See the [DOC](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js).
- **findNestedDependencies** : Instruct require to pick the dependencies from your entrypoint file. Traverse thorough the files and grab the dependencies for final build.

Rest is self explanatory or refer the [documentation](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js)

Well this saved me.

To use with the gulp build system see [`gulp shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) module, by this you can wireup your build system to automate the complete process.

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29051078/1848109) to know how to achieve this.

Hope this answer helps someone stuck same as me!