# AMD modules don't see libraries

Tags: jquery, module, gulp, requirejs, amd

I use Gulp for making up a project and RequireJS for AMD modules. Here is some code from gulpfile.js (libs.min.js includes libraries):

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['common-js'], function () {
  return gulp.src([
   'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
   'app/libs/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
   'app/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js',
   'app/libs/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js',
   'app/libs/font-awesome/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.min.js'
])
   .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts'));
});

gulp.task('common-js', function () {
var mainjs = gulp.src('app/scripts/modules/main.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts/modules'));

var configjs = gulp.src('app/scripts/config_require.js')
    .pipe(concat('config_require.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
```

});

Scripts included in html:

```
<!-- Some code -->
<script src="scripts/libs.min.js"></script>
<script data-main="scripts/config_require.min.js" src="scripts/lib/require.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

For example, I use some Bootstrap method in my module:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
var modals = {};

modals.initModals = function() {
    $('#carouselExampleFade').carousel();
};

return modals;
});
```

In a file which includes modules (main.js) I call my function:

```
define(['jquery', 'modals'], function ($, modals) {

/*Some code*/

modals.initModals();
});
```

Then, as you can see in gulpfile.js, main with all included modules is included in its turn in config_require.js:

```
"use strict";

requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'scripts',
paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-3.2.1.min',
    main: 'modules/main.min',
    modals: 'modules/modals'
    }
});

requirejs(['main']);
```

As a result I have the following error in a console:  "$(...).carousel is not a function". I have the same error with other plugins and frameworks (except jQuery). Does it mean that modules don't see the libraries? Or it's because of Gulp? Because if I include scripts separately in html the error disappears:

```
<script src="scripts/lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/test.js"></script>

//Test.js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#carouselExampleFade').carousel();
});
```

Comment: Also this may be an interesting read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978361/using-gulp-to-build-requirejs-project-gulp-requirejs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Just added that